# 400 Bad request on c# code

Tags: c#, bad-request

Getting an error exception thrown on this small piece of code but I can't figure out why / where. Fairly new to this so any help would be apprecaited

```
private void GetServiceData(string url)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Service) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            string name = string.Format("{0}Data", this.Service);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                data = client.DownloadString(url);
            }

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(name, data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Shared.Utilities.ExceptionLog.WriteExceptionToLog(ex, "CourseFinderServiceControl.GetServiceData()");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with debugging, take out the TRY/CATCH and you will get a specific error on your screen (right now, it is being written to a log). What is that specific error?

Comment: Please add your exception details

Comment: What is the "this.Service"?

Comment: Message:            The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for Twitch, you need to specify client when requesting the data.